Implicit Kirk Strategy proof in Bjerksund and Stensland (2006)
I'm reading this paper "Closed form spread option valuation" by Bjerksund and Stensland (2006). You can access the paper here: https://openaccess.nhh.no/nhh-xmlui/bitstream/handle/11250/164107/2006.pdf
In Appendix C, they derive a reformulation of the Kirk strategy but I don't know how they get to the last line shown below.
Consider:
$$
X_1 = F_1exp({-1 \over 2}v_1^2 + v_1\varepsilon_1) 
\\X_2 = F_2exp({-1 \over 2}v_2^2 + v_2\varepsilon_2)
$$
The two error terms are standard normal random variables with correlation $\rho$
Since the two variables follow a log normal distribution, we have:
$$
{aX_2^b \over E[X_2^b]} = a*exp\{{-1 \over 2}b^2v_2^2 + bv_2\varepsilon_2\}
$$
In page 14 of the paper, they show that:
$$
E[X_1I(X_1 \ge {aX_2^b \over E[X_2^b]})] \quad (1)
\\= E[F_1exp\{{-1 \over 2}v_1^2 + v_1\varepsilon_1\} I(F_1exp\{{-1 \over 2}v_1^2 + v_1\varepsilon_1\} \ge a*exp\{{-1 \over 2}b^2v_2^2 + bv_2\varepsilon_2\})] \quad (2)
\\ = F_1E[I(F_1exp\{{-1 \over 2}v_1^2 + v_1(\varepsilon_1 + v_1)\} \ge a*exp\{{-1 \over 2}b^2v_2^2 + bv_2(\varepsilon_2 + \rho v_1)\})] \quad (3)
$$
I understand the first two lines (from (1) to (2)) just fine but I don't know how they arrive at the indicator function in the last expression (3).
Thank you!
